# Which data type category is String

Tags: vba

As I understand, there are the 2 different ways to categorize data types in VBA.

- Object type vs. Non-Object
- Value type vs. Reference type

I would assume that object types are the same as reference types. But I read that there is a difference regarding assignment between object and non-object types:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Dim chrt As Chart
Set chrt = something
```

Notice the "Set". Now in the following link, String is categorized as reference type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

But

```
Dim str As String
Set str = "abc"
```

is wrong and

```
Dim str As String
str = "abc"
```

is correct. Thus reference type and object type is not equivalent. What is the difference?

Comment: The link you provided is about .Net and VB.Net, *not* VBA (which is COM-based, and not .Net-based).  In VBA you can regard strings as value types.  In the newer VB.Net however, on the one hand, the whole `Set..` business goes away, on the other hand, strings become real classes/objects, *but* VB.Net hides this somewhat for compatibility reasons (for instance, you don't have to use the `New` keyword with strings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your MSDN link is referring to **Visual Studio 2013 (.NET)**, where `String` is indeed an object (like everything in the .net framework).

VBA strings are values, not objects.

> As I understand, there are the 2 different ways to categorize data
>   types in VBA.
>
> - Object type vs. Non-Object
> - Value type vs. Reference type

It's simpler than that. An *object type* **is** a *reference type*, and a *non-object type* **is** a *value type*.

In VBA object references are assigned using the `Set` keyword; in the past, values used to be assigned using the `Let` keyword (I believe that still works, for compatibility reasons); that's why property setters use `Let` for value types, as in `Public Property Let Foo(value As Integer)`, and `Set` for reference types, as in `Public Property Set Foo(value As Object)`.

The language evolved and the `Let` keyword was eventually dropped for value assignations; `Set` remained required, for object reference assignations.

But in VBA a `String` is a *value*, like an `Integer` or a `Boolean`.

Answer (score 3):

VBA does have **Value Types** and **Reference Types**, but neither `Strings` nor `Arrays` fall *neatly* into either category.

It's informative to look at the definitions of Value types and Reference Types:

> **Value Type**
>
> - A data type is a value type if it holds the data within its own memory allocation.
>
> **Reference Type**
>
> - A reference type contains a pointer to another memory location that holds the data.

All `Objects` use pointers, so they are all `Reference Types`, while the following store their value at their memory location, so they are all `Value Types`:

- Boolean
- Byte
- Integer
- Long
- Single
- Double
- Date
- Currency

But `Strings` and `Arrays` are different. They **do** use pointers, so technically they are `Reference Types`, **but** the VBA language semantically treats `Strings` and `Arrays` as `Value Types`.

As such, when working with `Strings` and `Arrays`, VBA has the following behaviors:

- It is not necessary to use the `Set` keyword when assigning to a `String` or `Array` (unless you're assigning to a member of an `Array` of objects).
- Assigning the value of one `String` or `Array` to another creates a **copy** of the value.
- The equality operator for comparing `Strings` is the `=` operator.